# How do I check whether dates are in chronological order in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a large data set with 4 date columns (let's say Date_1, Date_2, Date_3, Date_4). I would like to check whether Date_1 occurs before Date_2, Date_2 before Date_3, and Date_3 before Date_4. How would I do this? I've thought of doing a nested if statement but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Please add small example along with expected output. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is similar to this :

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, Date_1 = structure(c(18534, 18544, 18536, 
18547), class = "Date"), Date_2 = structure(c(18533, 18539, 18540, 
18545), class = "Date"), Date_3 = structure(c(18532, 18535, 18543, 
18541), class = "Date"), Date_4 = structure(c(18537, 18550, 18545, 
18537), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#     id Date_1     Date_2     Date_3     Date_4    
#  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#1     1 2020-09-29 2020-09-28 2020-09-27 2020-10-02
#2     2 2020-10-09 2020-10-04 2020-09-30 2020-10-15
#3     3 2020-10-01 2020-10-05 2020-10-08 2020-10-10
#4     4 2020-10-12 2020-10-10 2020-10-06 2020-10-02
```

You can use `rowwise` with `diff` to check if all the date values occur before the next one.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(check = all(diff(c_across(contains('date'))) > 0))

#     id Date_1     Date_2     Date_3     Date_4     check
#  <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <lgl>
#1     1 2020-09-29 2020-09-28 2020-09-27 2020-10-02 FALSE
#2     2 2020-10-09 2020-10-04 2020-09-30 2020-10-15 FALSE
#3     3 2020-10-01 2020-10-05 2020-10-08 2020-10-10 TRUE 
#4     4 2020-10-12 2020-10-10 2020-10-06 2020-10-02 FALSE
```

In base R, you can do this with `apply` :

```
cols <- grep('Date', names(df))
df$check <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) all(diff(as.Date(x)) > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super helpful! Also thanks for the tip about how to ask a good question. I'm new here, but I will keep this in mind going forward!